# Static wired LAN IP without a DHCP router ("Link-Local Only") on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, lan, static-ip

Disclaimer: I the noobest noob when it comes to networking. I hardly have an idea what means what in a network setup. For me, there is no "trivial" information in this regard.

---

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine and a Raspberry Pi, on my home wired LAN network. In the current setup, the only thing in between these devices is a network switch:

```
[ Ubuntu ] ——— [ network switch ] ——— [ RPi ]
```

**I don't have a WAN internet connection on this network (and in the current setup I don't need one)**, as it is provided by another, a wifi interface. I use the wired LAN only to connect these devices.

Since there is no router on this LAN network to provide a DHCP config, in my network settings GUI, on the `IPv4` tab, I set "**Link-Local Only**".

My Ubuntu can see the RPi, and the RPi can see my Ubuntu, but only on the condition that first I look up each device's own IP address with `hostname -I`, and then I use that IP address when connecting (mounting).

I have noticed that these IP addresses can change after reboots. They don't always do, and sometimes they return to previously used values, yet, in effect these changes roll an obstacle in the way of easy connecting. I'd like to set a static IP for both devices; I guess on this site I can ask about **how to achieve it for my Ubuntu 20.04 machine**.

---

I think that there may be a number of ways to achieve my goal, either through some config file, or the Settings GUI, or even by running some terminal commands (that I could put in a script).

Please, when suggesting a solution, take into account my lack of networking knowledge: I'm not after the industry best-practice — I prefer a method that's easier to carry out for a beginner.

---

**Addendum:**

- I seem to be aware that on Ubuntu 20.04 `netplan` is often used in configuring networks; I have also seen `renderer: NetworkManager` in such configs.

  - Does this mean that I may have an option to avoid using netplan, and use something easier? (Netplan appears difficult as it seems to assume as a prerequisite a good level of networking knowledge.)
  - Would there be a way to override a netplan config with a terminal command "on the fly", comparable to how `xrandr` commands can "amend" X-server configs?
- In the Network Settings GUI, on the `IPv4` tab (where I choose "Link-Local Only"), there seems to be a *Routes* section, with *Address*, *Netmask*, *Gateway*, and *Metric* "fields", but these remain greyed out, even if I toggle the corresponding *Automatic* toggle to "off".

  - At the same time, the checkbox labelled *Use this connection only for resources on its network* also remains grayed out.

---

**Update: solution summary**

- For this to work, one needs to set corresponding static IPs on all involved devices.

  - corresponding means: `foo.bar.baz.x` and `foo.bar.baz.y`
- For the wired interface, one should choose an IP range [different from that of the wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347715/static-wired-lan-ip-without-a-dhcp-router-link-local-only-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2303525_1347729) interface's; e.g.:

  - wifi: `foo.bar.x.x`
  - wired: `baz.quux.x.x`
- On Ubuntu, on the Network Settings GUI's `IPv4` tab, one should choose "Manual", and proceed as per [@raj's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347729/1157519).
- On a Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi OS based on **Debian Buster**, the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file needs to be modified: it already contains a helpful-enough "static IP example" snippet. [More info on RPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920).

Comment: What is your questions/"goal"?

Comment: @paladin That when I run my mounting script, it can mount immediately, without the occasional bounce-back, where it says that the device is not accessible. A static IP would enable that smooth connecting every time, without having to muck with IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktop Ubuntu you don't have to use `netplan`, as there is Network Manager with a nice GUI to configure networking parameters.

Since you want a static IP, in the Network Settings GUI, in the `IPv4` tab, set the "Method" to "**Manual**" and not "Link-local only". Choose an IP address for your Ubuntu machine. This address should belong to one of **private** address ranges: 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x or 192.168.x.x. It is most popular to use the third one :) Let's assume that the IP address will be for example 192.168.200.1 (take care that the range doesn't collide with your WiFi connection; if WiFi happens also to use 192.168.200.x, choose another range). Click "Add" and in the "Address" column enter that address. In the "Netmask" column, enter 255.255.255.0. As you don't have any router on this network, leave the "Gateway" column empty. Click "Save" and after you disconnect and re-connect your wired connection, your configured address should be set on the interface.

Of course you must also set another static IP address from the same range (for example 192.168.200.2) on your RPi, but I don't know what OS do you have there and can't provide you more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you, now `hostname -I` already returns the set value, now I quickly see if I can use it as intended from the Raspberry...

Comment: note: 172.16.0.0/12 (172.16.x.x – 172.31.x.x)

Comment: So while I see the set IP in `hostname -I`, when I try to mount my Ubuntu shares on the RPi, I get "Connection timed out", and when I try to mount the Pi on the Ubuntu machine, I get "No route to host". (I have even restarted the network-switch.)

Comment: @bac0n I just wanted to describe things in a very simple way, so did not go into that :)

Comment: @Levente what IP your RPi has? You have to also set an address from 192.168.200.x on your RPi.

Comment: @Levente Both sides of the connection must have addresses from the same network, so both Ubuntu and RPi must be something from 192.168.200.x.

Comment: Ohhhh, so I need to set the Pi as well, within the same range! Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: @Levente do not mix the address range from your WiFi connection with the wired one. You must keep it different.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, both my mounting scripts work without a glitch on both Ubuntu and on the Pi. Thank you very much!